# Counting Permutations

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following task but I don't know how to get the right solution:

> How many permutations with $n \geq 8$ elements exist with exactly one
>   cycle of length $3$, two cycles with length $2$ and the rest with
>   cycles of length $1$.

Any Ideas?

edit:
I came to following solution:

n!/(24*(n-7)!)

Is that correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain the term *cycle* (and provide some more context in general).

Comment: @barak: *Cycle* does not need to be defined in this context: it’s a completely standard notion.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You need to choose $3$ of the $n$ elements for the cycle of length $3$, and then you need to choose a cyclic order for them; in how many ways can that be done?

Then you need to choose $4$ elements for the two $2$-cycles and divide them into two disjoint cycles; in how many ways can that be done?

Once all of that has been done, the permutation is completely determined (why?), so you need only combine those partial results correctly.